# How to reinstall Windows 7 Embedded?

Tags: windows-7, windows-embedded

I need to reinstall Windows 7 Embedded on my server but I'm not able to do so despite repeated tries.  I tried booting up the server with the Windows Embedded 7 Setup ISO attached (using IPMI) and I've also tried running setup.exe in the CDROM after Windows has booted up.  Both methods fail.

In the first case, the server simply reboots by itself after I selected "IBW" button.  In the second case, the installer returns some files missing while installing.

I'm sure my Windows Embedded 7 Setup ISO is correct, because earlier on, I used IBW on the same ISO to install Windows Embedded 7 onto the server.  Of course, the C drive has empty when I first installed.

What should I do?  I read that the normal Windows 7 (not embedded version) installer allows you to reformat the C drive before re installing.  There does not appear to be such an option for Windows embedded.

Appreciate any tip.  Thanks.

Comment: To clarify, Windows 7 Embedded on a 'server'..? Can I ask why would you do that?

Comment: Ops, I should mentioned, it's a rack server, but you still can install XP or Win7 on it.  As I'm using it headless, I'm treating it as a server anyway.

Comment: Yeah, I get that you can, I'm just curious as to what advantages you're gaining over using a normal operating system. It's not really what WES7 was designed for.

Comment: I'm using it for industrial communications, machine talking to machine. Rightfully, I should be using Linux as most of my competitors do but I'm having trouble porting. The normal operating system is considered too unstable. Win2k8 will also be overkill as I'm using entry level server running off ATOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using something like GParted to delete or format the current partitions on the disk.

Comment: Thanks. I'll select this as an answer even though I used Ultimate Boot CD and PartedMagic.  :)